# Is it ok to promote my services (not products) when answering a very broad question?

Tags: support, self-promotion

I am writing an answer to a fairly general question ([this one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/how-to-automate-functional-regression-tests-through-database-data-comparisons) to be specific), so I am giving a very general answer. Can I add at the end "*if you want more help, please contact me for consulting*" ? Is this kind of self-promotion allowed?

This is different from promoting a product, because a product is a very specific solution to the question. But promoting a service in this case is needed because the question was fairly broad and requires a whole consulting project to answer.

Comment: In short, no. But you can promote such services in your profile, and if your answers demonstrate quality and expertise, people will visit your profile to read more of your posts, and be exposed to the advertisement. In other words: the best marketing here is the visible quality of your work.

Comment: thanks, that answers the question! It really clarifies how to self-promote here. How can I mark the comment as the answer? Also, why was this downvoted? This is a genuine question I had. I did not find the answer anywhere else. I made sure to ask before actually doing it because I wanted to follow the rules. Why am I being punished for having a genuine question and wanting to know the rules?

Comment: Here on Meta, downvotes may mean that the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @MairaBay You can’t mark a comment as an answer. Feel free to post an answer yourself using content from the comment if you like. As for downvoting: I didn’t downvote you, and I can’t tell you what those who did were thinking with any certainty, but I can speculate. Voting is different on Meta. On Main, DVing a Q means “this Q is bad, I don’t want it on the site”. In Meta, DVing can mean that, or it can *also* mean “nothing is wrong with the Q per se, but I disagree with what it proposes”. Aka you’re asking “can I do X” and UV are a quick way to say “yes” and DVs a quick way to say “no”.

Comment: Thanks @Iamnotthewayyouspeak and Dan for clarifying! :)

Comment: @gnat yes and no. Yes as it pertains to self-promotion. But no because it is more about a specific *product*, and here I was talking more about my consulting *services*.

Comment: @WeareMonica. 1) That's why I said "yes and no". If I'd seen the answer about the product before asking this question, I would've still been in doubt & still posted the question **just to make sure**. That's why I decided to modify this question & keep it in case others think the same way. 2) Yes, the comment & answer have helped me, that's why I marked it as the answer.

Comment: 3) Adding a line about self-promotion was a second thought and not the reason why I was in SE answering questions. TBH I have never even noticed any ads on the site so I think it's not a good place to advertise. But thanks for the suggestion (despite the fact that it sounded more like bullying).

Comment: 1) Also, the questions about the product are very focused on a product being a **specific** answer to a **specific** question. I was talking about a question that is very **broad** (like "how do I build a house?").

Comment: This is strange, because I had accepted the answer (as soon as I saw it) and the arrow went green. Then when I went back to this page a few hours later the arrow was grey and I could not click on it. Now I tried again and the arrow was clickable and became green. There must be a glitch in their system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An answer on a Stack Exchange site should be self contained, complete and (duh) answer the question. That excludes that you are free to offer your services in all your answers.

In the Help Center the article on [promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) says:

> Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.

and

> you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

So if you answer a question where you can naturally include a reference to your consultancy work you're probably fine, if you end every answer and question with "Hire me!" you risk the post being flagged as spam and that will have severe consequences up to the point that your account might be deleted.

You might wonder if comments are a good fit to do this promotion but comments are only meant to either ask for clarification or point out issues with a post. They are not for promotion either.

if you want to make people aware of your services, use your about me. It is the place where you can tell about your self and promote stuff (within reason, as always).