# How to delicately promote a Stack Exchange related application to high-rep users?

Tags: discussion

I've read these questions:

- [Is it ok to promote my services (not products) when answering a very broad question? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339875/is-it-ok-to-promote-my-services-not-products-when-answering-a-very-broad-quest)
- [How do I mention my own products in answers? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers)
- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

And there are dozens more.

I'm not selling a product, but giving one away to high-rep Stack Exchange users. A product that lets them convert all their Stack Exchange Posts to their own website hosted on GitHub Pages.

I could easily track down and message high-rep users but that would "feel weird" if I didn't know them well.

Is there a method of submitting an application that benefits Stack Exchange users for review? Then if Stack Exchange Corporation likes it they would promote it (or at least list it somewhere) themselves?

Comment: Is this a product developed around Stack Exchange? And are you actually selling it?

Comment: @Makyen That is very close. Except my application doesn't run on Stack Exchange as a Web Browser extension. Rather it takes all your posts on Stack Exchange and converts them to your own website on GitHub Pages. I will study the potential duplicate in more depth tomorrow and close this question if I think it's a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: @Laurel Yes it is designed around all your Stack Exchange Posts and it extracts your posts to create your own website of all your work. I asked an earlier question and it's perfectly legal to take your work in Stack Exchange out and put it in your own website. No it's not for sale. It's free.

Comment: Because it's about the network, you can put it on Stack Apps. There's  all types of software there, including websites, even closed source ones. Search their site directly if you want examples.

Answer (score 9):

Just don't.

This will be the most delicate option.

Comment: Just don't ask Stack Exchange Corporation to showcase my product to high-rep users is your answer? PS peeking at your BIO your expertise in Python and Bash hints you would be interested in my product that converts Stack Exchange Posts to your own GitHub Pages website because it uses Python and Bash plus SEDE to achieve the results..

Comment: "just don't" is the answer to the question on "how to delicately promote to high-rep users".

Comment: I understand you were answering the title and not the question body. Fair enough.